# Don't get JSON-Data from PHP-Server / Ionic Application - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, ionic-framework

I searched every theme but didn´t find an answer.
I´m simply trying to get data from this address in to my ionic application,
but always get this:

```
{"$$state":{"status":0}}
```

I´m working with a factory:

```
.factory('Markers', function($http) {

 var markers = [];

    return {
    getMarkers: function(){

    return $http.get("http://geofence.obcc-dd.webseiten.cc/marian/markers.php").then(function(response){
      markers = response;
      return markers;
        });

        } }})
```

And this Controller-Code:

```
.controller('MapCtrl', function($scope, $state, $cordovaGeolocation, Markers) {
 var options = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true};

    $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then(function(position){

       console.log("Data:");  
       console.log(Markers.getMarkers()); //here the 0-state appears...

   var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
```

I can´t work on and can´t use the needed data.
Please help me - I´m freaking out... ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you sure

Call your service method like this

```
Markers.getMarkers(function(response){

 console.log(response); 

});
```

And define your service method like this

```
getMarkers: function(callback){

 $http.get("http://geofence.obcc-dd.webseiten.cc/marian/markers.php").then(function(response){
callback(response)
        });
} }})
```

Also there is other methods but best is already given please let me know output of the code because it is not tested.
if need clear solution please post code snippet or create plunker